# Regex For a Simple Validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

m working on some code where i need to have some validations and so i need a regex that could validate me to check if the entered string is in range of AB000001 to AB200000

could anyone please post the regex or even an alternate would do!!

Thanks Regards,

Comment: Spend a few minutes searching the internet for how to write your own regex, this is a site to help you when you are stuck and have tried to find a solution but can't, not to do work for you.

Comment: `entered string is in range of AB000001 to AB200000` Strings don't have ranges, only sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Regex will be difficult for this one, and that regex may look hideous as well.

Instead of the regex, you can split the String into two parts, first one will have only `AB` and the second one will have only the number. Then check the number whether its inside the range or not.

```
$string = "AB200000";
$splits = preg_split("/(?<=^AB)(?=\d{6}$)/", $string);
if($splits[1] >= 1 && $splits[1] <= 200000){
    print "bingo!\n";
}
```

You can use `substr()` instead of `preg_split()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can just use substr:

`function verif($input){
     return ((((substr($input, 0, 2) == 'AB') && (substr($input, 2, 6) >= 1)) && (substr($input, 2, 6) <= 200000)) );
}`

Answer (score 0):

Not what you want but a simple start to the hideous regexp method:

```
AB[012][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]  # would match    AB000000 to AB299999
AB[012][0-9]{5}                   # (same) matches AB000000 to AB299999
AB([01][0-9]{5}|200000)           # matches AB000000 to AB200000 (tantalisingly close)
```

Awkward that you wish to exclude AB000000 and AB200001(and above) :)

match AB000001 to AB099999:

```
AB(0[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]|0[0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]|0[0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9]|0[0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|0[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

match AB000001 to AB200000:

```
AB([12]00000|[01][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]|[01][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9]|[01][0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[01][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

Programatically it would be better to match AB([0-9]{6}), put number into variable.
Then check is number > 0 AND number <= 200000.

The regexps can be probably tightened up and different methods (e.g. a NOT match on numbers) used to make them shorter or work more simply.